# How do I prove Berman's theorem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

Berman's theorem states

> If a unary language ( a language with all the strings of the type $1^i$, $ i  > 0 $ ) is NP-Complete then P = NP.

I tried reducing SAT to a given unary language $L$ assuming it is NP-Complete. But I can't think of a way  such that after applying the reduction so that SAT gets solved in polynomial time. How do I proceed further?

This is an exercise from Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak , but not homework.

Comment: Googling "berman's theorem unary language P = NP" immediately turns up multiple answers to your question that show where to find a proof, including http://math.stackexchange.com/q/235162/14578, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_language, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_language.

Comment: @D.W. I was not able to follow the proof from wikipedia earlier. But after reading Yuval's answer given in the link by you and Shresh I understood it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235162/if-an-unary-language-exists-in-npc-then-p-np). Or see the paper by S. R. Mahaney, Sparse complete sets for NP: Solution of a conjecture by Berman and Hartmanis (Journal of Computer and System Sciences, 25:130-143, 1982).